# Ajax file, modules, and the request flow

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, kohana

I am creating my own module, and in some place in one of those module's files I'm using ajax. Now:

How should I call the file which I want to get the response from? I want to use kohana classes in this file, so getting there directly through a MODPATH gives me "class not found" of course.

How should I handle that?

I can't use routing, because I don't want to add new route in bootstrap just for one module. And I'm not so sure it's a good practice to allow module's classes for extending kohana controller.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Kohana you should use your module inside Controller anyway. Why don't you use Routes in bootstrap? It is made exactly for such tasks.